# Paint on top of a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a JPanel which has few JComponents added to it.
I have overridden paintComponent method of JPanel where I am drawing some shapes on JPanel.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(20, 6, 12, 12);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.setFont(FontStore.FRIENDS_BLOCK_OPTION_FONT);
    g.drawString("12", 26, 12);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

However the shapes which I am drawing through paintComponent is rendering behind the JComponent. 
How can I draw shapes whose z-index is higher than components added to JPanel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, use either a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) or [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) to paint over other components